# How to aggregate output with multiple keys in Python mapreduce reducer portion

Tags: python, mapreduce

I am fairly new at doing mapreduce and I am trying to do the following:

I have created a mapper that yields the following result:

```
12,United Kingdom:17850 15.3
12,United Kingdom:17850 20.34
12,United Kingdom:17850 22.0
12,United Kingdom:17850 20.34
12,United Kingdom:17850 20.34
12,United Kingdom:17850 15.3
12,United Kingdom:17850 25.5
12,United Kingdom:17850 11.1
12,United Kingdom:17850 11.1
12,United Kingdom:13047 54.08
12,United Kingdom:13047 12.6
12,United Kingdom:13047 12.6
12,United Kingdom:13047 30.0
12,United Kingdom:13047 9.9
```

where the result consist of month,country:customer customer spent

My mapper.py looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import sys
import re
from datetime import datetime
 
infile = sys.stdin
next(infile) 
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split(',')
    
    cust_ID = columns[6]
    country = columns[7]
    date = columns[4]
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
    M = '%02d' % date.month
    price = float(columns[5])
    qty = int(columns[3])
    
    print '%s,%s:%s\t%s' % (M,country,cust_ID, (price*qty))
```

I am very stuck on the reducer portion since my end goal is to have the results aggregated by Month and Country and then the value would be the top spending customer for each month and country combination. The end result would look something like the following: **Month,Country:Customer**.

My current reducer.py looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
 
current_key = None
current_value = 0
key = None
cur_month_country_key = None
cur_cust_id = None

for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip()
  key, value = line.split('\t', 1)
  month_country_key,cust_id = key.split(':')
  value = float(value)
  if current_key == key:
    current_value += value
  else:
    if current_key:
      print('%s:%f' % (current_key,current_value))
    current_value = value
    current_key = key
if current_key == key:
    print('%s:%f' % (current_key,current_value))
```

and I am able to get the following results from it:

> ```
> 01,Australia:12386:143.000000
> 01,Australia:12388:431.300000
> 01,Australia:12393:639.500000
> 01,Australia:12415:7092.980000
> 01,Australia:12422:238.500000
> 01,Australia:12431:384.680000
> 01,Australia:16321:87.750000
> 01,Belgium:12383:651.160000
> ```

where the results are month,country:customer:customerTotal

However this is not exactly my desire output as I am stuck on how to aggregate the reducer further so that it aggregates by month,country as the key, sorts by the highest customer spent and then arrive at the desire result of **Month,Country:Customer**.

Any inputs into how to proceed with my reducer would be very appreciated. I though of creating a dictionary to store the key-value pairs but then got stuck because I though I would need two dictionaries. One for the current month,country:customer key and another for customer and total spent. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about using pandas ? https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Hi @RobinFrcd, yeah doing it in pandas would be easier but sadly for this specific problem I cannot use pandas and need to to do it by reading a txt file line by line in my mapper and reducer codes.